# What size adapter do I need to fit a Danco hose on my older Glacier Bay kitchen faucet?

Tags: plumbing, hose, measuring, adapter

The pull-out (well, technically a pull-down) hose was leaking on our kitchen sink. It is a Glacier Bay–branded model but Home Depot did not show any hoses for it on their site so I bought a generic "Kitchen Faucet Pull-Out Spray Hose Replacement Kit" from Danco.

It looked just right in the package, and the output end adapter connected to the old sprayer just fine. But when I went to hook it up under the sink the new hose was slightly too big for the tube under the faucet!

The new hose came with all sorts of adapters but it turns out they're all basically the same thread size just for different male/female quick connects. I just have a simple threaded tube that doubles as a mounting bracket and none of the included adapters match it.

Here's what it looks like under the sink:

[image: Threaded brass tube protuding among some flexible covered hoses]

I think the Danco hose is considered <s>1/2"</s>1/4" thread — NPT if that's a safe assumption? My calipers show an "inner diameter" of 12.01mm when I expand it in the end of the hose:

[image: Caliper expanded in end of new hose]

But what would the slightly smaller size of the Glacier Bay fitting be? My calipers show an "inner diameter" of 11.08mm inside the fitting of the original hose:

[image: Caliper expanded in end of old hose]

Is the faucet fitting any sort of standard size? E.g. are there metric hose fittings, and if so what would the actual size be I should look for based on my "inner diameter" measurement?

Comment: I found this metric thread chart <https://www.adaptall.com/info-tutorials/identify-metric-threads.php> but the female ID jumps from 10.9 (M12 x 1.0) to 12.4 (M14 X 1.5) which isn't encouraging :-/

Comment: You need to know thread pitch in addition to diameter. You can pick up a set of thread pitch gauges (I'd imagine `<insert cheap tools store brand here>` would work just as well as a more expensive one, then go to your local big-box (pitch gauge in hand) and browse the adapters aisle. If they don't have it, head to a local plumbing store with all your dimensions. Keep in mind, you may _not_ make it from one piece to the other in one single fitting, it might take 2 or even 3 to get where you need to be.